# EXCEL VBA adding a new slide to Powerpoint Automatically

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

This is my code for exporting Contents from Excel to PowerPoint. My Problem is I have only one slide in the presentation. As the criteria is met,  VBA should automatically increase the slides and populate it. The slides should be of the same layout. After every IF and Else Loop I Need to add a new slide for the next Iteration. Using this code I get an error that Active X component cant create object. Any help ?

```
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
                strPresPath = "C:\Users\asehgal\Desktop\OPL\Presentation1.pptx"

            On Error Resume Next
            Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

                If oPPTApp Is Nothing Then



                Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
                oPPTApp.Visible = True 'msoTrue

                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
                SlideNum = 1
                oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
                Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table 1")

                On Error Resume Next
                If oPPTApp.Windows.Count > 0 Then
                Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation

                Set pptSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
                Else

                    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Add

                    Set pptSlide = oPPTFile.Slides.AddSlide(1, ppLayout)
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0      
                Do
            'if topics are same
            If (arrThema(p, 0) = arrThema(p + 1, 0)) Then

                With oPPTShape.Table
                .cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = arrThema(p, 0)
                'if true Adda new slide here for the next iteration
                End With

                'If subtopics are also same
                If (arrThema(p, 1) = arrThema(p + 1, 1)) Then


                Else 'if subtopics are different

                With oPPTShape.Table

                .cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = arrThema(p, 1)
                .cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = Beschreibung(p)
                'if true Add a new slide here for the next iteration            
                End With

                oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
                Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table 1")
                With oPPTShape.Table
                .cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = arrThema(p + 1, 1)
                .cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = Beschreibung(p + 1)
                'if true Adda new slide here for the next iteration

                End With

               ' MsgBox "Description : " & Beschreibung(p)
                End If


                Else


                'add a new slide here and add the details there
                With oPPTShape.Table
                .cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = arrThema(p, 0)
                .cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = arrThema(p, 1)
                .cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.text = Beschreibung(p)

    'if true Adda new slide here for the next iteration

                    'code for adding a new slide which does not work
                Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
               Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)

                End With



            End If
            p = p + 1
           Loop Until p = noThema
```

Comment: @JamieG If you could help

Answer (score 0):

Use this code whever you need to insert a new slide, it will add the slide to the end of the presentation and apply your custom layout

```
Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.Slides.AddSlide(oPPTApp.Slides.Count + 1, pptLayout)
```

**Edit**

Apologies, I couldn't test it myself. Try the edited code above

Comment: ERROR 429 : Active X component cant create an object

Comment: ERROR 438 : object doent Support this property or method.

Comment: `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate` this code works fine for me. But after creating a new slide it gives a Type Mismatch error. Any Idea ?

Comment: I'm afraid not,  I can't test the code at the minute so i can't troubleshoot

Comment: I just modified the code by adding ActivePresentation after the oPPTApp object. It works and creates a new Slide but that is a new Title Slide. I want the same slide as I am using i.e. sort of a duplicate of the same slide.

Comment: Are you referencing the correct layout for pptLayout?

Comment: No, I dont want to refer to a pptLayout. I have myself created a table in ppt and want to use the same table in every slide. that is the reason I am trying to duplicate the slide.

Comment: Apologies, you didn't mention in your question that you want to duplicate the slides, you state they need the same layout and reference pptLayout in your code. Try  Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(oPPTAppActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Duplicate  pptSlide.MoveTo(oPPTAppActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong Interpretation of the question. I guess I tried the same Thing which you stated., The Count here is 1 for me so I directly states `.Slides(1)` . But Still I tried your code as well. Again the same Problem. It creates a duplicate slide but gives a TYPE MISMATCH error just after that.

Comment: I've missed some stops out form the code i posted, can you try this for me please? Change oPPTAppActivePresentation to oPPTApp.ActivePresentation

Comment: yes yes dont worry. I already did that. I just want to get rid of this TYPE MISMATCH error.

Comment: Is the error being thrown on that line? Can you step through the code and see where the error in thrown please?

Comment: for my code it Shows error at `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate`  and for your code it Shows error at `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(oPPTAppActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Duplicate`. So basically, It is at the same line.

Comment: I've just tested the code on my machine and the following works fine for me `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Duplicate
pptSlide.MoveTo (oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)`

Comment: `pptSlide.MoveTo (oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)` is a new command . right? I mean it shoukd go in the next line ?

Comment: Correct yes it should

Comment: I got what was wrong. Duplicate Returns a range. not a slide. The correct Version was : `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate.Item(1)`

Comment: Odd, the original code works on mine. Glad it's working for you though